# How can showing 2d array in map loop at React?

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I got an error while practicing 2d array in React

This is part of my code,

```
const Component = () => {
    var seat = [
        "1111x111111111111x1111",
        "1111x111111111111x1111",
        "1111x111111111111x1111",
        "1111x11111111111xx1111"
    ]   // example data

...

function create2DArray(row, col) {
      arr = new Array(row)
      for(var i=0; i<row; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(col);
      }
      return arr;
    }
var arr = create2DArray(row_cnt, col_cnt)

return (
...
{
              seat.filter((obj, key) => {
                var temp = obj.split('')
                for(var i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
                  arr[key][i] = temp[i];
                }
              })
            }
        {/* problem here map */}
            {
              arr.map(obj => {
                obj.map((obj2, key) => {
console.log('obj2', obj2, 'key', key)
                  return <div className='seat_num'>
                      <span key={key}>{obj2}</span>
                  </div>
                })
              })
            }
...
)
```

Component not updating after map.
When I checked with console.log(obj2), I confirmed that the data was entered normally.
How can I showing to {obj2}?

chrome console result

```
Component.js:57 obj2 1 key 0
Component.js:57 obj2 1 key 1
Component.js:57 obj2 1 key 2
Component.js:57 obj2 1 key 3
Component.js:57 obj2 x key 4
Component.js:57 obj2 1 key 5
Component.js:57 obj2 1 key 6
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue may come from a component rendering faster then your variable is initialized. I would save your array into a useState in order to re-render your component once your array is fully initialized:

```
    const Component = () => {

    const [array, setArray] = useState([]);        

    var seat = [
        "1111x111111111111x1111",
        "1111x111111111111x1111",
        "1111x111111111111x1111",
        "1111x11111111111xx1111"
    ]   // example data

...

function create2DArray(row, col) {
      arr = new Array(row)
      for(var i=0; i<row; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(col);
      }
      return arr;
    }


useEffect(() => {
  var arr = create2DArray(row_cnt, col_cnt);
  setArray(arr);
},[]);

return (
...
{
              seat.filter((obj, key) => {
                var temp = obj.split('')
                for(var i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
                  arr[key][i] = temp[i];
                }
              })
            }
        {/* problem here map */}
            {
              arr.map(obj => {
                obj.map((obj2, key) => {
console.log('obj2', obj2, 'key', key)
                  return <div className='seat_num'>
                      <span key={key}>{obj2}</span>
                  </div>
                })
              })
            }
...
)
```